# How do I have LVM/LUKS clean itself up on unplug?

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd, lvm, luks

I have an external drive with the following partitioning scheme:

```
LUKS Container (crypt-desk)
|
|- LVM Container (desktop-hdd)
   |
   |- Backup (ext4)
   |- Desktop Files (ext4)
```

This is mounted on USB through my dock, and usually works pretty well.

However, if I remove my drives without unmounting them, my system gets stuck in a problematic state where I can't use my drive. LVM doesn't "clean up" after itself, so all of the old partition references are still around . As such, LUKS will refuse to clean up, quoting that things are still "in use."

My configuration is pretty generic. LUKS automounts using a key file, and then LVM will auto-mount the backup drive. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there some configuration step I can use to ensure that everything is cleaned up following an unclean/forced unmount?

Comment: I guess now you know why we unmount a partition lol.

The correct command is `umount` or to remove the partition from your graphical interface. As far as I know you have to decrypt the LUKS, then ready LVM, and run fsck. If you continue to do this data loss is likely, especially with LUKS.